# switching from @keyframe to tranistion animation doesn't work

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform

On loading state I have a `@keyframes` animation running.

```
@keyframes graph-line-loading {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

When I stop the animation `graph__line` **jumps** to `translateY()` value (set inline).

However the `background-color` does nicely animate.

I would expect transition property working on `transform` as well.

```
.graph__line {
  transition-property: transform, background-color;
}
```

If the `background-color` is included in `@keyframes` animation it doesn't get transitioned on state change either.

Seems like whatever property is animated in `@keyframes` gets ignored by transition property even though `@keyframes` is added via different class.

**Plz check the fiddle.**

https://jsfiddle.net/LukaG/m4bzk6e3/

Any ideas?